# Blender error: out of memory

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, error, memory-management

I have never used Blender, so I'm totally new to the software, but today a friend of mine asked me to use my computer to render a picture for him since he doesn't have a powerful PC. So he gave me the file and told me what to do:
For both the two star-shaped bushes and the small ball-shaped bushes, I had to:

1)Select the object with the right click of the mouse
2)Click on the icon with the stars (the particle system)
3)Click on Display modifier in the viewport
4)In Emission, increase the number up to 100k

Then, I had to set a resolution of 6000 on x-axis and 4080 on the y-axis and start the render.
The resolution must be so high because the picture is going to be printed on 6mx4m rollups.

My PC's specs are:

- i7 920 @4GHz (4 core, 8 threads)
- 12GB DDR triple channel @1600MHz CL9
- nVidia gtx 1070 AMP!Extreme 2GHz on the GPU and 9000MHz on the 8GB of GDDR5
- SSD 850 pro
- HX750i 750 W PSU
- Windows7 Ultimate x64
  I have downloaded the last 64bit version of blender.

Every time I try to render, I'm getting the "out of memory error" before the render even starts (I get it when it starts to apply textures, I think, but I'm not sure).
I would like to know if there is anything I can do (is my PC not good enough or is a picture problem?).
I will attach a screenshot of the image (the original is 3,9 GB and when I open it, 11GB of ram are used). If you need more information about the picture tell me where to find them and I will report them.
I also tried to render with my GPU but I get the same error even if both AIDA64 and GPU-Z tells me that only 2GB of GDDR is being used.

Thanks. [image: render]

Comment: You are simply ran out of memory. If your scene is around 11GB and you have 12GB (note that system and other software is using a bit o it) it simply isn't enough. And when you try to render it textures are applied, maybe you have set particles higher number for render and maybe same thing with subsurface modifier. Also render resolution has a big factor here. You can try to break your scene to render layers and then use composite to join them.

Comment: You have too many particles in your scene

Comment: So I supose this is true also for my GPU, right? Even if softwares tell me that only 2GB out of 8 are being used, when the render should starts, I don't have enough GDDR5 for it to begin, right?
Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 5):

Only 25 million faces and lots of particles in 6k resolution... why would you be running out of memory?

As pointed out in the comments you have no RAM left in your system.

Working in 3D is very easy to create situations where your scene is much greater than the resources on your computer.

You really need to reassess where you need to optimize. The trick is to think of where it is that you need great detail and where you can get away with less. The art of 3D is part precision but is mostly optimization.

For example, textures that are going to be just a few pixels on the screen can be rougher than those that are going to be featured in close-up. 
Do you need that many particles or would a surface with a bump map would give you the same?

Not every strand of grass in the distance has to be a particle, The ones you don't see don't have to exist, the statues don't have to be as detailed if they are going to be so small, etc.

When Rendering on GPU you have even less resources than when you render on CPU, so it is unlikely that you will be able to use it to render such an ambitious projecet.

You need to slice the project in different layers that your computer can handle and composite later.

Here's a link that details how to do this: https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/how-to-render-a-complex-scene-without-crashing

Comment: Ok. I will tell to my friend what to do. As I said, I'm just lending him my PC I don't know all the image's specs. Only the resolution and the grass's particles but I don't know how the software works, that's why I'm asking, no need of sarcasm, but thanks. Also I have read in the blender manual that rendering  with the GPU is better than rendering with the CPU and also that 8k textures need 256MB of memory so that's why I got confused about the memory problem.
Thanks for the help

Comment: GPUs can sometimes render faster (they are not "better"), but have less vRAM generally, hence the comment.

Comment: @cegaton The first sentence in your answer have made my day :).