# How to prevent Blender from crashing when running out of memory?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, performance

I'm waiting for like 5 minutes for a render to start, nothing happens (Blender 2.90.1) and Blender is crashing in the end. I already tried to render the project using Blender 2.83.8 but I'm getting the same issue. As you can see from the screenshot, I'm running out of memory since I only have 16gb RAM and it's showing me that blender is using 20.34gb. The viewport is fine however, I can see the image resolving and everything...

[image: 1]

**Q:** Is there any chance to render my image although I don't have enough memory?

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange, I believe the crash should be reported as a bug, rather than posted as a question, my advice is to make sure that your file is optimized to suit the specs of your machine, adding more information would help too, how many vertices do you have? what render engine are you using? ... etc.

Comment: i have never used this site before that why i didn't know where to post it , I'm sorry tho , i have 155,769 vertices and the render engine is cycels as i mentioned i hope this information could help you to find a solution for me

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76068/cycles-cuda-out-of-memory-on-final-render-but-not-on-preview and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84466/blender-error-out-of-memory

Comment: No problem @ilyesbouabdelli , you can read more about BSE in the meta, concerning the crashing issue, as I mentioned, try first to update the drivers for your graphics card, if that doesn't work, report a bug from within blender, in the help menu

Comment: @Georges Crashes caused by running out of memory are *not* a bug and should *not* be reported on the bug tracker. Optimizing the scene is the way to go, Blender has to work within the limits the hardware and operating system sets.

Comment: @RobertGützkow check the OB comment, he has 155.769 vertices, I believe memory is very unlikely to be the issue, on the other hand, I had similar issues before, that turned out to be because the graphics card drivers are outdated, which is what I suggested to be done first

Comment: @Georges They have explicitly stated that they have 16 GB RAM and 20.34 GB are being used, which is also shown in the screenshot. So it's clearly running out of memory and Windows can't compensate by using a page file on disk. Geometry is not the only part that require memory, for instance large textures could also contribute to this.

Comment: @RobertGützkow I guess you're right.

Answer (score 2):

If you are out of memory, the only solutions are to install more RAM in the computer, or to make the paging file (virtual memory stored on disk) in the OS larger.

Or work in scenes that do not exceed the resources available in your computer. Don't abuse the number of particles, use instances instead of duplicates, use modifiers and set subdivision surface to low values [Blender render crash when using subsurf modifiers.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28222/blender-render-crash-when-using-subsurf-modifiers)

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Linux system: I had a similar problem. I bought additional memory, 64GB, but was not enough. What I found out that if you are on a Linux system, you can increase swap space, for instance to additional 64GB on your Nvme drive. Once the RAM memory starts to run out, the swap space will be used. This way your render will not crash.

[image]